# Получить значения с HTML-страницы после срабатывания javascript'а

Tags: c#

Привет :)

Такой вопрос возник. Имеется HTML-страница, на которой работает джаваскрипт. Скрипт раз в 5 секунд меняет значения переменных в табличке.
Необходимо считать значения переменных, которые появляются. Попробовал просто спарсить страницу GET-запросом, но вместо значений переменных получил название джаваскриптовой переменной. Собственно, как решить этот вопрос? Пытался что-то найти в интернете, но толком ничего и не нашел.

Если интересует конкретика, то необходимо получать данные в реальном времени с этой страницы http://warehouse.funcube.org.uk/realtime.html (знаю, что там есть .csv файл, но там не все данные).

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не пробовал, но можно посмотреть в сторону Selenium http://scraping.pro/example-of-scraping-with-selenium-webdriver-in-csharp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по исходному коду, раз в 5 секунд идет обращение к URL http://warehouse.funcube.org.uk/ui/realtime/2.json, откуда и подставляются значения в таблицу. Вам будет достаточно выполнить запрос к этому ресурсу и распарсить JSON.

Comment: Оу, и в правду. Спасибо :)

Comment: В общем случае, если содержимое страницы зависит от выполнения javascript, нужно использовать что-то вроде PhantomJS.